# ajax not calling to spring boot controller

Tags: jquery, ajax, spring-boot

When I am calling ajax call to the spring boot controller class, it is not calling to the controller, it is saying  400 (Bad Request) error. I tried all the possibilities but its not working, when I am setting up as **processedData: false** then in that case it is calling to the controller class but getting only null. When I tried the other possibilities then it is always giving error as **TypeError: Converting circular structure to JSON**

This is my ajax code which I tried to resolved my issue but no luck.

```
function personalDetailsPage() {
    var status = false;
    var actualYear = getCurrentAge();
    if (actualYear < 18) {
        $("#userDateofBirthValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>You are under 18. Please select correct age</font>");
        $("#dateOfBirth").focus();
        return false;
    }
    else {
        $("#userDateofBirthValidation").html("");
        $("#userDateofBirthValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    if ($(".image_preview").find('canvas').length == 0) {
        $("#fileuploadValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please upload your photo</font>");
        $("fileuploadValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#input").focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#fileuploadValidation").html("");
        $("#fileuploadValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    if ($("#describedYourSelf").val() == "") {
        $("#describeYourselfValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please write something about your self</font>");
        $("describeYourselfValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#describedYourSelf").focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#describeYourselfValidation").html("");
        $("#describeYourselfValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    if ($("#birth_FName").val() == "") {
        $("#birthFNameValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your birth first name</font>");
        $("birthFNameValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#birth_FName").focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#birthFNameValidation").html("");
        $("#birthFNameValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }


    if ($("#birth_LName").val() == "") {
        $("#birthLNameValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your birth last name</font>");
        $("birthLNameValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#birth_LName").focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#birthLNameValidation").html("");
        $("#birthLNameValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    if ($("#dateOfBirth").val() == "") {
        $("#userDateofBirthValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your full name</font>");
        $("userDateofBirthValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#dateOfBirth").focus();
        event.preventDefault();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#userDateofBirthValidation").html("");
        $("#userDateofBirthValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }



    if ($("#placeOfBirth").val() == "") {
        $("#userPlaceOfBirthValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your Place of Birth</font>");
        $("userPlaceOfBirthValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#placeOfBirth").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userPlaceOfBirthValidation").html("");
        $("userPlaceOfBirthValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    if ($("#timeOfBirth").val() == "") {
        $("#userTimeOfBirthValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your Time of Birth</font>");
        $("userTimeOfBirthValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#timeOfBirth").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userTimeOfBirthValidation").html("");
        $("userTimeOfBirthValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    if ($('#religion option:selected').val() == "Select Religion") {
        $("#validationReligion").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Religion</font>");
        $("validationReligion").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#religion").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;
    }
    if ($('#religion option:selected').val() == "") {
        $("#validationReligion").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Religion</font>");
        $("validationReligion").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#religion").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;


    } else {
        $("#validationReligion").html("");
        $("validationReligion").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    if ($('#caste option:selected').val() == "select") {
        $("#userCasteValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Caste</font>");
        $("userCasteValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#caste").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    if ($('#caste option:selected').val() == "") {
        $("#userCasteValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Caste</font>");
        $("userCasteValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#caste").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#userCasteValidation").html("");
        $("userCasteValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    if ($("#subcaste").val() == "") {
        $("#userSubCasteValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your actual sub caste</font>");
        $("userSubCasteValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#subcaste").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userSubCasteValidation").html("");
        $("userSubCasteValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    if ($("input[name=manglikStatus]").is(':checked') == false) {
        $("#ManglikRadioValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Manglik Status</font>");
        $("ManglikRadioValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("input[name=manglikStatus]").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#ManglikRadioValidation").html("");
        $("ManglikRadioValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    if (($("input[name=gender]").is(':checked') == false)) {
        $("#GenderRadioValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Gender Type</font>");
        $("GenderRadioValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("input[name=gender]").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;
    }
    else {

        $("#GenderRadioValidation").html("");
        $("GenderRadioValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    if ($('#heighestEducation option:selected').val() == "select") {
        $("#HeightEducationListValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Highest Education</font>");
        $("HeightEducationListValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#heighestEducation").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    if ($('#heighestEducation option:selected').val() == "") {
        $("#HeightEducationListValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Highest Education</font>");
        $("HeightEducationListValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#heighestEducation").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#HeightEducationListValidation").html("");
        $("HeightEducationListValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    if ($('#employedIn option:selected').val() == "select") {
        $("#validationEmployedInValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Employment Status</font>");
        $("validationEmployedInValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#employedIn").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    if ($('#employedIn option:selected').val() == "") {
        $("#validationEmployedInValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Employment Status</font>");
        $("validationEmployedInValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#employedIn").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }

    else {
        $("#validationEmployedInValidation").html("");
        $("validationEmployedInValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    if ($("#designation").val() == "") {
        $("#userDesignationValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please Enter NA if you are not working</font>");
        $("userDesignationValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#designation").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userDesignationValidation").html("");
        $("userDesignationValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }


    if ($("#employerName").val() == "") {
        $("#userEmployerNameValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please Enter NA if you are not working</font>");
        $("userEmployerNameValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#employerName").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;


    } else {
        $("#userEmployerNameValidation").html("");
        $("userEmployerNameValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    if ($("#monthlyIncome").val() == "") {
        $("#userMonthlyIncomeValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your Monthly Income</font>");
        $("userMonthlyIncomeValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#monthlyIncome").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userMonthlyIncomeValidation").html("");
        $("userMonthlyIncomeValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    if ($('#maritalStatus option:selected').val() == "select") {
        $("#maritalstatusValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Marital Status</font>");
        $("maritalstatusValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#maritalstatus").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    if ($('#maritalStatus option:selected').val() == "") {
        $("#maritalstatusValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Marital Status</font>");
        $("maritalstatusValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#maritalstatus").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#maritalstatusValidation").html("");
        $("maritalstatusValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }






    if ($('#presentCountry option:selected').val() == "select") {
        $("#userPresentCountryValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Present Country</font>");
        $("userCountryCodeValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#presentCountry").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    if ($('#presentCountry option:selected').val() == "") {
        $("#userPresentCountryValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Present Country</font>");
        $("userPresentCountryValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#presentCountry").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#userPresentCountryValidation").html("");
        $("userPresentCountryValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }




    if ($('#presentState option:selected').val() == "select") {
        $("#userPresentStatesValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Present States</font>");
        $("userPresentStatesValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#presentState").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    if ($('#presentState option:selected').val() == "") {
        $("#userPresentStatesValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Present States</font>");
        $("userPresentStatesValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#presentState").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#userPresentStatesValidation").html("");
        $("userPresentStatesValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }



    ////
    if ($('#presetAddressCity option:selected').val() == "select") {
        $("#userPresentcityAddressValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Present City</font>");
        $("userPresentcityAddressValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#presetAddressCity").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    if ($('#presetAddressCity option:selected').val() == "") {
        $("#userPresentcityAddressValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Present City</font>");
        $("userPresentcityAddressValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#presetAddressCity").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#userPresentcityAddressValidation").html("");
        $("userPresentcityAddressValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    /////



    if ($("#presentAddress").val() == "") {
        $("#userPresentAddressValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your Present Address</font>");
        $("userPresentAddressValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#presentAddress").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userPresentAddressValidation").html("");
        $("userPresentAddressValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    if ($("#presentAddressZip").val() == "") {
        $("#userPresentAddressZipValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your Present City Zip code</font>");
        $("userPresentAddressZipValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#presentAddressZip").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userPresentAddressZipValidation").html("");
        $("userPresentAddressZipValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    ////
    if ($('#permanentCountry option:selected').val() == "select") {
        $("#permanentCountryCodeValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Permanent Country</font>");
        $("permanentCountryCodeValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#permanentCountry").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    if ($('#permanentCountry option:selected').val() == "") {
        $("#permanentCountryCodeValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Permanent Country</font>");
        $("permanentCountryCodeValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#permanentCountry").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#permanentCountryCodeValidation").html("");
        $("permanentCountryCodeValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    /////

    ////
    if ($('#permanentState option:selected').val() == "select") {
        $("#userPermanentStatesValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Permanent State</font>");
        $("userPermanentStatesValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#permanentState").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    if ($('#permanentState option:selected').val() == "") {
        $("#userPermanentStatesValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Permanent State</font>");
        $("userPermanentStatesValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#permanentState").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#userPermanentStatesValidation").html("");
        $("userPermanentStatesValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    /////
    ////
    if ($('#permanentAddressCity option:selected').val() == "select") {
        $("#userPermanentCityValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Permanent City</font>");
        $("userPermanentCityValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#permanentAddressCity").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    if ($('#permanentAddressCity option:selected').val() == "") {
        $("#userPermanentCityValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please select your Permanent City</font>");
        $("userPermanentCityValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#permanentAddressCity").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    }
    else {
        $("#userPermanentCityValidation").html("");
        $("userPermanentStatesValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    /////


    if ($("#permanentAddress").val() == "") {
        $("#userPermanentAddressValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your Permanent Address</font>");
        $("userPermanentAddressValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#permanentAddress").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userPermanentAddressValidation").html("");
        $("userPermanentAddressValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }



    if ($("#permanentAddressZip").val() == "") {
        $("#userPermanentAddressZipValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your Permanent City Zip code</font>");
        $("userPermanentAddressZipValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#permanentAddressZip").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userPermanentAddressZipValidation").html("");
        $("userPermanentAddressZipValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    if ($("#OfficeAddress").val() == "") {
        $("#userOfficeWorkAddressValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your Office/Business Address. If you are not working, please write NA</font>");
        $("userOfficeWorkAddressValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#OfficeAddress").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userOfficeWorkAddressValidation").html("");
        $("userOfficeWorkAddressValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }
    if ($("#officeAddressCity").val() == "") {
        $("#userOfficeWorkAddressCityValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your Office/Business City. If you are not working, please write NA</font>");
        $("userOfficeWorkAddressCityValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#officeAddressCity").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userOfficeWorkAddressCityValidation").html("");
        $("userOfficeWorkAddressCityValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }


    if ($("#officeAddressCityZip").val() == "") {
        $("#userOfficeWorkAddressZipValidation").html("<font color='red' style='font-family:arial;font-size:80%;'>Please enter your Office/Business City Zip code. If you are not working, please write NA</font>");
        $("userOfficeWorkAddressZipValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        $("#officeAddressCityZip").focus();
        status = false;
        return false;

    } else {
        $("#userOfficeWorkAddressZipValidation").html("");
        $("userOfficeWorkAddressZipValidation").removeClass("d-none");
        status = true;
    }

    if (status == true) {
        var profileImage = $(".image_preview").find('canvas');
        var description = $("#describedYourSelf").val();
        var fName = $("#birth_FName").val();
        var lName = $("#birth_LName").val();
        var dob = $("#dateOfBirth").val();
        var placeOfBirth = $("#placeOfBirth").val();
        var timeOfBirth = $("#timeOfBirth").val();
        var religion = $('#religion option:selected').val();
        var caste = $('#caste option:selected').val();
        var subCaste = $("#subCaste").val();
        var manglik = $("input[name=manglikStatus]").is(':checked');
        var gender = $("input[name=gender]").val();
        var heighestEducation = $('#heighestEducation option:selected').val()
        var employedIn = $('#employedIn option:selected').val()
        var designation = $("#designation").val()
        var employerName = $("#employerName").val()
        var monthlyIncome = $("#monthlyIncome").val()
        var maritalStatus = $('#maritalStatus option:selected').val()
        var presentCountry = $('#presentCountry option:selected').val()
        var presentState = $('#presentState option:selected').val()
        var presentCity = $('#presetAddressCity option:selected').val()
        var presentAddress = $("#presentAddress").val()
        var presentAddressZip = $("#presentAddressZip").val()
        var permanentCountry = $('#permanentCountry option:selected').val()
        var permanentState = $('#permanentState option:selected').val()
        var permanentAddressCity = $('#permanentAddressCity option:selected').val()
        var permanentAddress = $("#permanentAddress").val()
        var permanentAddressZip = $("#permanentAddressZip").val()
        var officeAddress = $("#OfficeAddress").val()
        var officeAddressCity = $("#officeAddressCity").val()
        var officeAddressZip = $("#officeAddressCityZip").val()

        var data = {
            profileImage: profileImage,
            description: description,
            fName: fName,
            lName: lName,
            dob: dob,
            placeOfBirth: placeOfBirth,
            timeOfBirth: timeOfBirth,
            religion: religion,
            caste: caste,
            subCaste: subCaste,
            manglik: manglik,
            gender: gender,
            heighestEducation: heighestEducation,
            employedIn: employedIn,
            designation: designation,
            employerName: employerName,
            monthlyIncome: monthlyIncome,
            maritalStatus: maritalStatus,
            presentCountry: presentCountry,
            presentState: presentState,
            presentCity: presentCity,
            presentAddress: presentAddress,
            presentAddressZip: presentAddressZip,
            permanentCountry: permanentCountry,
            permanentState: permanentState,
            permanentAddressCity: permanentAddressCity,
            permanentAddress: permanentAddress,
            permanentAddressZip: permanentAddressZip,
            officeAddress: officeAddress,
            officeAddressCity: officeAddressCity,
            officeAddressZip: officeAddressZip
        };
        console.log(data)
        console.log(jQuery.fn.jquery);
        var url = "/user/addPersonalDetails"
        $('.loader').show();
        $.ajax({
            url: url,
            contentType: 'application/json',
            type: 'POST',
            data: data,
            //processData: false, [tried with this option also but no luch]
            
            success: function(result) {
                $('.loader').hide();
                $('.personal-details-div').hide();
                $('.personal-details-icon').removeClass('active');
                $('.family-details-icon').addClass('active');
                $('.family-details-div').show();
                $('.additional-details-div').hide();
                $('.devotional-details-div').hide();
                $('.Partner-details-div').hide();
            }, error: function(jqxhr) {
                $('.loader').hide();
                console.log(jqxhr);
            }
        });
    }

}
```

This is my controller class code...

```
@RequestMapping(value ="/addPersonalDetails", method = RequestMethod.POST,produces="application/json")
    public @ResponseBody ResponseEntity<List<String>> savePersonalDetails(@RequestBody PersonalDetails personalDetails, Model model, HttpServletRequest request){
        String parameter = request.getParameter("profileImage");
        String parameter2 = request.getParameter("description");
        String birth_FName1 = request.getParameter("birth_FName");
        String lName = request.getParameter("lName");
        String birth_FName = personalDetails.getBirth_FName();
        String birth_LName = personalDetails.getBirth_LName();
        System.out.println(birth_FName1);
        System.out.println(lName);
        System.out.println(birth_FName);
        System.out.println(birth_LName);
        System.out.println(parameter);
        System.out.println(parameter2);
        return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>(HttpStatus.OK);
    }
```

Comment: You are sending JSON not individual request parameters. Use an object which has those fields and use `@RequestBody`.

Comment: I tried with json also but still not working. I tried like this way  var data = {
            "profileImage": profileImage,
            "description": description,
            "fName": fName,
            "lName": lName,
            "dob": dob,
            "placeOfBirth": placeOfBirth,
            "timeOfBirth": timeOfBirth,
            ...
     ...
            "officeAddressZip": officeAddressZip
        };

Comment: Changing the client doesn't help you need to change your controller!

Comment: in controller also, I have added as @RequestBody to accept the data but not working. Please help me in troubleshooting my issue.

Comment: You have changed the controller but aren't using it. You are still retrieving them from the request. Your controller is just wrong you only need the `@RequestBody`.

Comment: If you see I am trying to access it from RequestBody as well which is  personalDetails.getBirth_LName(); but still not working. Also, I changed to ajax request something like this url: url,
   headers: {
    'Accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
   },
   // contentType: 'application/json',
   type: 'POST',
   data: JSON.stringify(data), but getting 400 Bad Request error and not calling the controller class

Comment: What makes you think it that `fName` in JSON will automagically be bound to `Birth_FName` that isn't going to happen without either configuration or the proper names for the properties (which normally should match the JSON ones). You cannot have name x1 in json and then expect to bind it to x2 in your object.